# Create a function with a if loop

Tags: r

I'm a beginner on R so I coded like that. But I would like to know how to get this code "lighter". I know that I can use functions but I don't know how. Can you help :

```
  for(i in 1:x){

  if ((id_base_full$Bucket.Amount[i] >= 150000))  {
    id_base_full$Case.Number[i] <- 1

  }else if(startsWith(id_base_full$HI.Event.Type[i],"4")||
           startsWith(id_base_full$HI.Event.Type[i],"1")||
           startsWith(id_base_full$HI.Event.Type[i],"2")){
    id_base_full$Case.Number[i] <- 1

  }else if ((id_base_full$HI.Long.Term.Flag[i] == "Yes"))  {
    id_base_full$Case.Number[i] <- 1

  }else if ((id_base_full$HI.Relevancy[i] == "Obsolete"))  {
    id_base_full$Case.Number[i] <- 1

  }else{ 
    id_base_full$Case.Number[i] <- 2  

  }
  next [i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the function `case_when()` in the `dplyr` package will help you to apply functions to the rows/columns of a data frame, the below snippet applies the conditional logic to the variable `HI.Event.Type`, from this, a new variable `new_var` is created.

`my_data %>% 
     mutate(new_var = case_when(
      HI.Event.Type %in% c(4,1,2) ~ "1",
      TRUE ~ "baseline value")`

see the `dplyr` docs here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/